# C# No Exception variable required

Tags: c#, exception

In the below code no object declared for IndexOutOfRangeException-

```
class ExcDemo1 {
    static void Main() {
        int[] nums = new int[4];
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Before exception is generated.");
            // Generate an index out-of-bounds exception.
            for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                nums[i] = i;
                Console.WriteLine("nums[{0}]: {1}", i, nums[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("this won't be displayed");
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) {
            // Catch the exception.
            Console.WriteLine("Index out-of-bounds!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After catch block.");
    }
}
```

I just want to know is it permissble? and if yes can we do same thing in java also? and what is the advantage of this ?

Comment: [Why not try it?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), you may not need the variable, as your code snippet has shown.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague. I guess you are trying to ask if we are allowed to catch exception without declaring a variable for it in the below code
`catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) {
// Catch the exception.
Console.WriteLine("Index out-of-bounds!");
}`
 If that's your question? then yes, we can do that.

Comment: but how about java? Can we do same thing in java also i.e Exception without variable.

Comment: No. Java doesn't allow it. You need to provide a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) {
```

Is perfectly legal in `C#`. You need not specify a variable in the `catch` if you don't plan to use it.